# Generalizations of Mordell's theorem on rational quadrilaterals

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Mordell proved that every quadrilateral in the Euclidean plane is arbitrarily close to a quadrilateral whose sides and diagonals are rational. What if we take five points in the plane? Is there a choice of 5 bad points so that for some positive epsilon, whenever the points are moved at most distance epsilon then two of them are at irrational distance?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342018/mordells-theorem-on-rational-quadrilaterals without any notice to either site. Peter, that's an abuse of the system.

Comment: My apologies. I did not intend any offence.